# Numbers working as adjektives

Tags: numbers, adjective

> Das Turnier ist eine Begegnung **dreier** Schulen.
>
> auf allen **vieren** kriechen

Can someone please explain to me the grammar behind using numbers as adjectives? Examples would help a lot.

Comment: In the first example the number isn't used as an adjective, but as the number of the genitive object: "The tournament is a meeting of three schools". In the second example I don't see an adjective either. "Alle viere" may be akin to a substantive.

Comment: I'm thinking this is too broad a question. Any good grammar will have a chapter or section on numerals/numbers and it seems like you're asking for something like that here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjectives can be used in three ways:

- attributive

  > Die **lauten** Tenöre verlassen die Bühne.
  > <sup>The **loud** tenors leave the stage.</sup>
- predicative

  > Die Tenöre sind **laut.**
  > <sup>The tenors are **loud.**</sup>
- adverbial

  > Die Tenöre singen **laut.**
  > <sup>The tenors sing **loudly.**</sup>

But also some other word can be used in these functions, for example numerals perfectly qualify as attributes:

> Die **drei** Tenöre verlassen die Bühne.
> <sup>The **three** tenors leave the stage.</sup>

Here the nominal group »die **drei** Tenöre« was the subject, i.e. in nominative case. But you can also use this group as an attribute of another noun. To do so, you just need to transfer »die **drei** Tenöre« into genitive case and attach it as an attribute at the right side of another noun (here: *Auftritt*):

> Der Auftritt **der drei Tenöre** begeisterte das Publikum.
> <sup>The performance of **the three tenors** thrilled the audience.</sup>

But you also can talk not about *"the"* three tenors, but about any three tenors. In this case you don't have an article, and the genitive case is marked by a modification of the attribute:

> Der Auftritt **dreier Tenöre** begeisterte das Publikum.
> <sup>The performance of **three tenors** thrilled the audience.</sup>

So, in such a construction the word ***»dreier«*** is still a numeral, not an adjective. But although it's not an adjective it still is used as an attribute of a noun (*»Tenöre«*). And with this noun it builds a nominal group (*»drei Tenöre«*) which itself is the genitive attribute of another noun (*»Auftritt«*), and *»dreier«* is just the genitive form of the numeral *»drei«.*

---

In you other example is an error. This is the correct version:

> auf allen **V**ieren kriechen
> <sup>crawl on all fours</sup>

[Die Vier](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Vier) is a noun (in English: *the fours*). So it's neither a numeral nor an adjective.